# Send mail with queue method but it's sending directly

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm try to send mails after jobs finished, but I like send to queue. But my code send directly.

My code it's according [Queueing Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail)

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->queue(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Well this it's process

**app\Mail\CpJobFinished.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
...

class CpJobFinished extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use  SerializesModels, Queueable;

    ...
    // Some code for formating message
```

On one Command class **\app\Console\Commands\CpRsyncJobs**

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Mail\CpJobFinished;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
...

class CpRsyncJobs extends Command

Mail::to($email)->queue(new CpJobFinished($job));
```

But with this code mail it's send directly instead send to queue.  Of course, queues are active, work for other task,

Comment: If the queue is empty it's normal to be sent directly.. Using queues doesn't mean it will wait until your job is finished.. how does it work for other task?

Comment: Cron it's stopped for debug process. Task not inserted on jobs table. If you send any task to queue, this task it's a new entry on table jobs. My code not send task to jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Error on declaration of Class mailable.

When this code, mail it's send to queue.

**app\Mail\CpJobFinished.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
...

class CpJobFinished extends Mailable // implements ShouldQueue 
{
     use Queueable, SerializesModels;
```